# GridLayout in ScrollView not use xml

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-gridlayout

I want to insert GridLayout in ScrollView.
Only Source Code.
I want to implement like this xml.

```
<ScrollView
  <GridLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            :
            :
```

I don't know how how to write "android:layout_height" and "android:layout_width" in Java Code.
Please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to supply the appropriate `LayoutParams` when adding the child view.

The appropriate class depends on the parent (e.g. `LinearLayout` expects `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, `RelativeView` expects `RelativeView.LayoutParams`, &c). `ScrollView` is a customized `FrameLayout` and, like it, uses `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

```
ScrollView scrollView = ... ; // assume you already have this.
GridView gridView = new GridView(...);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, rameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
scrollView.addView(gridView, lp);
```